# What's the meaning behind the open-eyed stones that are placed on the deceased?

Tags: game-of-thrones

Numerous times throughout the series the deceased are shown with stones over their eyes, and with those stones painted with blue, open eyes.

What's the meaning behind this?

Comment: I think there’s an episode of the TV series where one character explains it to another. It might be Tyrion explaining it to Tommen after Joffrey dies. But I remember something about it is explained.

Comment: “We close our eyes in this world and open them in the next.” https://acourseindying.com/the-origins-of-the-eye-stones/

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The High Sparrow comments on this to Jaime about Myrcella Baratheon's funeral. In his words the reason is:

> **HIGH SPARROW:** Do you know why we use these stones? To remind us not to fear death. We close our eyes on this world and open them on the next.
>
> <sub>*Game of Thrones*, Season 6 Episode 2, "Home"</sub>

It's worth noting that this also has a real world precedent in that in various cultures around the world it is/was custom to place coins on the eyes during the funeral.

Comment: Thank you. I was not free to properly research the quote.